How to keep the logo in the center of the video component in any resolution of the screen
I have a React component that has a video with a company logo in the center, but when I switch to a responsive screen like a cellphone the logo keep getting out of the video, how do I fix this?
PC Version

Iphone Version

import videoJacare from '../imgs/ny4k.mp4';
import imgTest from '../imgs/LogoFecapFinanceOriginal2.png';
import styled from "styled-components";

function video(){
  return(
    <Intro>
      <Logo src={imgTest} alt="" />
      <Jacare
        src={videoJacare}
        poster={imgTest}
        loop
        autoplay="true"
        muted
        playsInline
        preload
        disablePictureInPicture
      >
        Seu navegador não suporta o elemento de vídeo.
      </Jacare>
    </Intro>
  );
}

const Jacare = styled.video`
width: 100%;         
  height: auto;        
  max-height: 80vh;    
  object-fit: cover;   
  align-items: center;
`

const Texto = styled.h1`
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
`

const Intro = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
`

const Logo = styled.img`
  position: absolute; 
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 25%;
  max-height: 25%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
`

export default video;

I've tried using position properties and setting the z-index to ensure the logo stays within the video, but it still gets out of the video. Nothing seems to work.

Although the information is incomplete, did you try to give your video position:relative?

As far as I understand, the centering of your logo is achieved using position: absolute. To prevent your logo from overlapping with other elements, ensure the Intro component has position: relative.
